# DNN + Form and list module + xslt + skin path..?

Tags: xslt, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I use the "Form and list" module for DotNetNuke to generate blocks. In those blocks I have an image that is located in a "image" folder in the skin directory. But I don't know how to get the link from the xslt file.

I would like this kind of link :

`<%= SkinPath %>images/foo.jpg` (in an aspx page)

If someone has any idea...

Thanks. :)
Florent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did this but had to include the entire path /Portals/0/....  etc.
I don't know of any dynamic tokens available at the XSLT level. It would be kind of ugly but you can pass dynamic data to your query in your forms & list. So tabid, or portalid etc. Then in your query you could query the portals table or tab, and get the skin used... and piece that together in your XSLT.  Would probably work and be dynamic, but ugly.